# How to compare content form textarea with values from array with php?

Tags: php, arrays, post, textarea

I want to check if the content from a text area contains certain "bad words".
I read the content from the textarea with `$_POST['message']`
This is my textarea:

```
<textarea class="form-control" name="message" placeholder="MESSAGE"></textarea>
```

All the bad words are in an array:

```
// read bad words into array
$blacklistfile = 'blacklist/badwords.txt';
$blacklistarray = file($blacklistfile, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
```

To check if the content of `$_POST['message']` contains any of these bad words, i thought: put all the content of `$_POST['message']` into an array and compare these arrays.

I tried in the textarea [] after the message:

```
<textarea class="form-control" name="message[]" placeholder="MESSAGE"></textarea>
```

and:

```
$usermessage = $_POST['message'];
print_r($usermessage);
```

But `print_r()` gives me no output

So how can i put the content of the textarea into an array??

Or: maybe there are other possibilities to achieve this?

Comment: Your textarea only sends _one_ single string value. What do you hope to achieve, by wrapping that in an array? You would still have an array consisting of only one element then.

Comment: You should loop over your bad words, and then check if they are contained in the value you got from the text area.

Comment: (How rather pointless such a naive approach eventually is though, is clear right from the beginning, I hope? If you don’t let me post `ass`, then I will try `a.s.s.` or `a-s-s` instead.)

Comment: There are a lot of ways you could filter the message as a string instead of an array as well. Like @CBroe says, it all depends on what's acceptable and what isn't. is `a-s-s` acceptable? if everything besides the full word(so without spaces next to eachother) is acceptable You can just post the message as string and use the php function `explode` and explode on a space. Or even another way. There's a lot of ways of achieving this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your textarea will submit one string

```
<textarea class="form-control" name="message" placeholder="MESSAGE"></textarea>
```

On server you must explode this string on spaces to get array of words

```
$textareaValue = $_POST['message'];
$wordsToCheck = explode(" ",$textareaValue);
```

Also you can filter unique words to avoid duplicate iteration

```
$wordsToCheck = array_unique($wordsToCheck);
```

After that, you can compare each textarea words to badlist

```
foreach ($wordsToCheck as $word){
    if(in_array($word, $blacklistarray)){
        //word is bad
    }else{
        //it's ok
    }
}
```

Did I understood your question correctly?